# WPF/.NET Thread sending keypresses to other processes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, input

I am working on a WPF (.Net Core 6) automation project where I want to send key presses to another application running on the system. The WPF application, once activated, is running a background worker thread in a while loop listening for a predetermined key press from the keyboard. When the key is pressed, I want to send another key press to another application/process. Since this is WPF I can't use `System.Windows.Forms` and `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");`.

So far I have tried the following without success:

1. [InputManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)
   With this I ran into some issues with the background worker thread running into some errors for [STAThread]. I believe I managed to solve this issue, but no key was able to be sent using this function.

```
        public static void Send(Key key)
        {
            if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
            {
                if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
                {
                    var e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key)
                    {
                        RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
                    };
                    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e);

                    // Note: Based on your requirements you may also need to fire events for:
                    // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent
                    // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyUpEvent
                    // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyUpEvent
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Adding reference to System.Windows.Forms.
   I tried adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms so that I could use [SendKeys.SendWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). But Visual Studio would not recognize the SendWait functions and System.Windows.Forms did not seems to be referenced even after being added manually.

Is there anyway to replicate `SendKeys.Send` for WPF .Net Core projects without involving extreme complex solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: The Win32-API routine that "sends" user input (incl keyboard and mouse input) would be "SendInput" https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput
Consider PInvoke'ing it https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SendInput.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by using ["InputSimulator" library](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator).

```
InputSimulator inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyPress(virtualKeyCode);
```

Where "virtualKeyCode" is of the class `VirtualKeyCode`. If you use this, you might need to convert the key you want to press into the correct `VirtualKeyCode`